# Using action bar in API 8

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to use Action Bar in my applicaiton which has API level 8.

I want it like in this picture, on the top with some items in it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tJ10.png

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Action Bar Sherlock Library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) which supports for below versions too. You can integrate that in your project and do your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Shadows answer is correct, but you can also use the [appCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) support library, which is an official android support library (for what that's worth).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://www.actionbarsherlock.com) library.
or using android support library